# Using mingw with opencv -- init error

Tags: opencv, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse CDT for developing C with mingw. I also add opencv libary. Everything compiled without problems. But if I start the compiled application (using a opencv-function) there is an init error. If I only include the .h-files without using a function it works.

The code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Streaming!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Streaming!!!
    // Nothing but create a window
    cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Error-Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdmT7.png

If I do not use a cv.. - function there will be no init error. Even if I include opencv2/opencv.hpp

I do not have an idea how it works.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Can you include error to your question?

Comment: I add an error image ... unfortunately it is in german.

Comment: have you tried to debug it? in wich line application crashes? or at the very beginning?

Comment: It does not reach the first line. the stacktrace is: ntdll!LdrAccessResource() at 0x7c91e514 
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject() at 0x7c91df5a 
ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection() at 0x7c929b23 
ntdll!RtlEnumerateGenericTableLikeADirectory() at 0x7c911046 
0x198e174 
ntdll!RtlSetEnvironmentVariable() at 0x7c934d2d 
ntdll!NtAccessCheckByTypeResultListAndAuditAlarm() at 0x7c98e174 
0x58fd30 
ntdll!LdrCreateOutOfProcessImage() at 0x7c91e457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The opencv-dll-files for mingw are damaged. I rename the visualstudio dlls to the names of the mingw-dlls and put it directly to in the exe folder and it works.